# Javascript replace parameters with Pattern

Tags: javascript

I just want to replace all parameters in a string based on a pattern :

For example:

```
var myString = "Hello Mr.{param1}, today is {param2} and hope ...";
```

I don't know how we can find `{#}` pattern and replace with the value in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replace(str, params) {
    for(var i in params)
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(i))
            str = str.replace('{'+i+'}', params[i]);
    return str;
}
replace("Hello Mr.{param1}, today is {param2} and hope ...", {
    param1: 'foo',
    param2: 'bar'
}); // "Hello Mr.foo, today is bar and hope ..."
```

Note that only the first occurrence of each parameter will be replaced.

---

If you want to replace all occurrences, in `replace` use

```
str = str.replace(
    new RegExp(
        ('{'+i+'}').replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\|]/g, '\\$&'),
        'g'
    ),
    params[i]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `format()` function to the `String` prototype like this:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var s = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
        s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i]);
    }

    return s;
};
```

Then you can call `format()` on any string like this:

```
var myString = 'Hello Mr. {0}, today is {1} and hope ...';
var formattedString = myString.format('John Doe', 'April, 19, 2014');
```

`formattedString` will be: `Hello Mr. John Doe, today is April, 19, 2014 and hope ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex with `replace`, something simple like:

```
function format(str, obj) {
  var re = /\{(.+?)\}/g;
  return str.replace(re, function(_,m){return obj[m]});
}
```

And use it like:

```
format('Hello, my name is {name}, I am {age} years old', {
  name: 'Peter',
  age: '30'
});
//^ Hello, my name is Peter, I am 30 years old.
```